# What is the reason that my Macro Made PowerPoint is Showing Error "Upload Blocked" After Completing Macro via Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

First, I want to start off by stating that I know this is not the most practical way of doing this, but I have tried 100 other examples and nothing has worked. My initial goal to refresh PPT links via Excel VBA have been unsuccessful.For some background info, my boss has an Excel spreadsheet that he has our project status on. I am displaying that with a Raspberry Pi via PowerPoint on a TV monitor. I have made a macro button in Excel to where when he hits the "refresh" macro button after adding more to the spreadsheet, it will automatically update the PowerPoint. Everything is working beautifully, except when I go to reopen the PowerPoint after the refresh, this is what I see: [image: Error When I reopen PPT after Macro Refresh]

Now, for my code.

Sub CopyRangeToPowerPoint()

```
'Declare PowerPoint Variables

Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Dim SlideTitle As String

Dim exlRange As Range
Dim filePath As String

'Opening PowerPoint and Creating a new Presentation

Set PP = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set PPPres = PP.Presentations.Add

'PP.ActiveWindow.WindowState = ppWindowMinimized


'Defining the path
filePath = ("PathToFile\TV Display PowerPoint.pptx")

PP.DisplayAlerts = ppAlertsNone

'Adding a new slide in PowerPoint Presentation and selecting that slide for further use
For i = PPPres.Slides.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(i)
    PPSlide.Delete
Next i


Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutLargeObject)
PPSlide.Select

Set exlRange = Range("A1:H45")

exlRange.Copy

PPSlide.Shapes.Paste


PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True



PP.Activate
PPPres.SaveAs (filePath)


'PP.ActiveWindow.WindowState = ppWindowMaximized
PPPres.Close
PP.Quit


Set PPSlide = Nothing
Set PPPres = Nothing
Set PP = Nothing
```

End Sub

I have a feeling that it has to do with the fact that I want to keep saving over the same path but I need it to be in the same location. Any ideas or suggestions greatly appreciated! I am an intern and would love to make a good impression :)

Comment: PPT barking about Upload Blocked suggests that you're saving the file to the cloud. Or rather, your boss is when hitting the refresh button and running your macro. But it's not clear who's opening the file and getting the error message afterward, you or the boss. Might it be a permissions issue on the file you're working with or the fact that it's open on somebody else's computer when you try to work with it?

Comment: I am saving it to a cloud in order to make is accessible to everyone in the company, maybe this is not necessary? I am the one getting the error message afterwards., not my boss. The file was not opened and it is my file so it should not be a permission issue.

Comment: I'm assuming you're opening the file from the cloud; is that correct?  What happens if you download it to your local hard drive and open it from there?  And before opening it, rightclick, choose Properties and see if the file's blocked; unblock it if so and then try opening it. I'm wondering if Microsoft's new stricter policies re files from the 'net might have something to do with this.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Yes, I am also opening from the cloud. Could it possibly be that I'm not giving PPT enough time to go through the steps before quitting? Maybe I need to let it sleep so to speak. Because I am noticing that it is not happening every time, just sometimes. Which leads me to believe it is not a matter of the file being blocked.

Comment: >> Which leads me to believe it is not a matter of the file being blocked.
Despite the error message that says that it is?  Again, try to isolate the problem by leaving the cloud out of it as I suggested before.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg If the file was in fact locked or blocked and Microsoft was allowing me to periodically over ride these security settings, then me and Microsoft need to have a little chat. I fixed my problem though. I changed the way that the presentation was saved and it works fine now. I will post my code in this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that solved my issue. I believe the way I was saving it before was causing this "upload blocked" error message.

```
Sub CopyRangeToPowerPoint()



'Declare PowerPoint Variables

Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Dim SlideTitle As String

Dim exlRange As Range
Dim filePath As String

'Opening PowerPoint and Creating a new Presentation

Set PP = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlManual

End With


Set PPPres = PP.Presentations.Open("PATH TO FILE")
PP.DisplayAlerts = ppAlertsNone
'PP.ActiveWindow.WindowState = ppWindowMinimized





'Deleting current slide 
For i = PPPres.Slides.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(i)
    PPSlide.Delete
Next i


Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutLargeObject)
PPSlide.Select

Set exlRange = Range("A1:H45")

exlRange.Copy

PPSlide.Shapes.Paste


PP.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True



PP.Activate



    With Application

    .Calculation = xlAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

PPPres.Save
PPPres.Close
PP.Quit


Set PPSlide = Nothing
Set PPPres = Nothing
Set PP = Nothing



End Sub
```